# Firebase crashlytics reports many insight available crashes in my app

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, phasset, firebase-crash-reporting

Below is my code

```
    func getImageFrom(_ asset: PHAsset, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
        let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = .current
        let size = CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 150.0)

        imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, 
        options: nil) { (image, info) in
            guard let img = image else { return }
            thumbnail = img
        }
        completion(thumbnail)
    }
```

I'm using this function to get an Image from PHAsset.

some time crash is reported at 
`thumbnail = img` or at `completion(thumbnail)`.

using this function in below code block

```
func getImageDataAndFindDupImages() {
   var i = 0
   var similarImages = [OSTuple<NSString, NSString>]()
   similarImages = OSImageHashing.sharedInstance().similarImages(with: .high) { () -> OSTuple<NSString, NSData>? in
       #if DEBUG
       print(i)
       #endif
       var tuple = OSTuple<NSString, NSData>()
       if self.tempArrAssets.count > 0 {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.lblNumberOfPhoto.text = R.string.localizable.scanning_photos_number("\(i+1)", "\(self.arrPhotoAssets.count)")
           }
           if !self.tempArrAssets.isEmpty {
               let tempArrAsset = self.tempArrAssets.removeFirst()
               self.getImageFrom(tempArrAsset) { (imageAsset) in
                   self.arrImageFromAsset.append(imageAsset)
                   if let imgData = imageAsset.pngData() {
                       tuple = (OSTuple<NSString, NSData>(first: NSString(string: "\(i)"), andSecond: imgData as NSData))
                   }
               }
               i += 1
               return tuple
           } else {
               return nil
           }
       } else {
           return nil
       }
   }
   print("To make dup tuples:", Date().timeIntervalSince(self.date))
}
```

I'm using `getImageFrom` in `getImageDataAndFindDupImages`

This is a log for the crash

```
Crashed: com.apple.mobileslideshow.accessCallbacks
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18a874020 objc_retain + 16
1  Duplicate Cleaner              0x1001f0e80 closure #1 in DuplicatePhotoFinderVC.getImageDataAndFindDupImages() + 519 (DuplicatePhotoFinderVC.swift:519)
2  Duplicate Cleaner              0x1001f16a4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@owned OSTuple<NSString, NSData>?) + 4338357924 (<compiler-generated>:4338357924)
3  CocoaImageHashing              0x1004f3514 -[OSSimilaritySearch similarImagesWithProvider:withHashDistanceThreshold:forImageStreamHandler:forResultHandler:] + 46 (OSSimilaritySearch.m:46)
4  CocoaImageHashing              0x1004f3924 -[OSSimilaritySearch similarImagesWithProvider:withHashDistanceThreshold:forImageStreamHandler:] + 95 (OSSimilaritySearch.m:95)
5  CocoaImageHashing              0x1004f28d0 -[OSImageHashing similarImagesWithProvider:withHashDistanceThreshold:forImageStreamHandler:] + 222 (OSImageHashing.m:222)
6  CocoaImageHashing              0x1004f27b0 -[OSImageHashing similarImagesWithHashingQuality:withHashDistanceThreshold:forImageStreamHandler:] + 201 (OSImageHashing.m:201)
7  CocoaImageHashing              0x1004f2734 -[OSImageHashing similarImagesWithHashingQuality:forImageStreamHandler:] + 190 (OSImageHashing.m:190)
8  Duplicate Cleaner              0x1001ee63c DuplicatePhotoFinderVC.getImageDataAndFindDupImages() + 316 (DuplicatePhotoFinderVC.swift:316)
9  Duplicate Cleaner              0x1001ee434 DuplicatePhotoFinderVC.fetchPhotosandCheckforDuplicate() + 146 (DuplicatePhotoFinderVC.swift:146)
10 Duplicate Cleaner              0x1001eea1c closure #1 in DuplicatePhotoFinderVC.checkForPermissionAndScanPhotos() + 162 (DuplicatePhotoFinderVC.swift:162)
11 Duplicate Cleaner              0x10021bdec thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned PHAuthorizationStatus) -> () + 4338531820 (<compiler-generated>:4338531820)
12 Photos                         0x195ff9098 __39+[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:]_block_invoke + 64
13 AssetsLibraryServices          0x19f048edc __79-[PLPrivacy _isPhotosAccessAllowedWithScope:forceHandler:accessAllowedHandler:]_block_invoke.14 + 520
14 AssetsLibraryServices          0x19f01486c __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a7fe610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a7ff184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a7ab404 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a7abdf8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 420
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a7b5314 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18a84eb88 _pthread_wqthread + 276
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18a851760 start_wqthread + 8
```

I'm not able to understand why I'm getting these crashes. If you have any knowledge please guide me.

Comment: Please share the crash log as well

Comment: @RohanBhale Added crash log

Comment: Is there any other info in the logs?

Comment: @RohanBhale, Unfortunately, No. This is the log from crashlytics

Comment: Does requestImage(for: targetSize: contentMode: options:completionHandler:) call the completionHandler multiple times or on other thread? Cause if it does then you have an issue as variables are not thread safe and could cause problems if being written and read from different threads. In this case the 'thumbnail' variable.

Comment: @RohanBhale yes, I'm using this function in for loop type datastream manner so it is getting called hundreds of times per second. can you suggest me some solution for this?

Comment: You will need to share the code where this method is being called in a loop. It could also be a memory issue

Comment: If you do that much amount of work I suspect it to be a memory issue

Comment: @RohanBhale added code block which uses function in question.

Comment: The answer below should solve your crash issue.

Comment: Thank you for your Solution. I have implemented this solution and let's see if it helps me. This bug is quite difficult to reproduce so wait and see if I got crash in crashlytics.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `nil` to **options** parameter in the `imageManager.requestImage(for:targetSize: contentMode:options:)`. If you pass nil as options, the method calls the completion block asyncrohonously. So there is a chance by the time your completion block gets called the method `getImageFrom(: completion:)` has exited and the local variable `thumbnail` has been destroyed(I am not talking about the UIImage object being destroyed but the variable which holds address of the UIImage itself). Then trying to set the thumbnail varibale which is no more on the stack, inside the block might be the reason there is a crash.

To solve your problem Create an instance of `PHImageRequestOptions` set its `isSynchronous` property to **true** like so.

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.isSynchronous = true
```

Now pass this `options` as a parameter to the `imageManager.requestImage(for:targetSize: contentMode:options:)`

As a result your `imageManager.requestImage(for:targetSize: contentMode:options:)` will call the block synchronously meaning before the `getImageFrom(: completion:)` method exits and so the variable `thumbnail` is still alive on the stack to be used.

Hoping this should solve your problem.

PS: Take care you call the method `getImageFrom(: completion:)` in a background thread or your main thread will be frozen